# WPF Card Design

Tags: c#, wpf, windows

How can I design an application that contains a card that can be flipped and have content on both side?

The card is something like a post card which has images on 1 side and then the messages on another side. It should be able to be rotated smoothly as well.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The download site has moved around and there doesn't seem to be a documentation page for it anymore, but I think the [Bag of Tricks](https://github.com/thinkpixellab/bot) still includes a FlipTile3D control that lets you define both sides of a tile, and lets you flip it over like a playing card.

Comment: +1 I immediately thought of the Bag of Tricks when I read the question.

Comment: BOT is certainly a good open source project in promoting the use of WPF.

Answer (score 1):

If you want content on two sides, I recommend Josh Smith's `ContentControl3D`:

- [Introducing ContentControl3D](http://joshsmithonwpf.wordpress.com/2009/02/23/introducing-contentcontrol3d/)

It does exactly what you want and includes a variety of configurable 3D transition effects.

There is also a detailed CodeProject article on the control:

- [Rotating WPF Content in 3D Space](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/WPF/ContentControl3D.aspx)

Comment: This is a great post explaining how we can have content on both sides. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Rotating from one content to another is a basic WPF/silverlight skill.

Here is a link to a blog post that shows how to rotate to display a cube.  If you wanted to show only two faces, rotate 180 degrees instead of 90.

http://oldschooldotnet.blogspot.com/2009/11/how-to-create-your-own-silverlight-cube.html

Answer (score 0):

You need to create the card as a 3d panel with the necessary controls on each side. I would recommend referencing this control as a starting point:

http://flipcontrol.codeplex.com/releases/view/22358

Answer (score 0):

just have a look at this post

http://www.interact-sw.co.uk/iangblog/2007/05/17/wpf-flippable-3D-list